# Get Polymer Error in Chrome after update to new Chrome version

Tags: polymer-1.0

My current Chrome version is `Version 47.0.2526.73 (64-bit)`

I notice that the error

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Request scheme 'chrome-extension' is unsupported
```

only occurs after I update Chrome.

I don't know is it some problem with Polymer, or Chrome error?

A screenshot for that:

[image]